# Match ("Hi") but not (text("Hi"))

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using this RegEx: `\"([^"]+)?\"`. This matches a basic quoted string, like `"Hi"`. I need:

1. To match: `("content")`
2. To **not** match: `(div:("content"))`
3. To **not** match something like: `(div:(div:(span:("content"))))`

What RegEx should I use?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to match in the above examples. Everything within the parenthesis, or just the quoted strings?

Comment: i want to match the `"content"` only if its just `("content")`

Comment: So you want to match quoted strings that are surrounded by parenthesis but not nested?

Comment: `grep b | grep -v ab` would return all the strings with substrings matching pattern `b` but not pattern `ab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in the format you specified, you could make sure that it doesn't end with an extra parentheses.

`\("([^"]+)"\)($|[^\)])`

That will match `("content")`, but will not match `(div:("content"))` or `(div:(div:(span:("content"))))`.

Comment: This doesn't match: `("content")`...i tested the reg in my regexp tester.

Comment: I made a slight change to it (see edited post), I had it either find the EOL or not a parentheses. I've tested it in Notepad++, http://regexpal.com/, and http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and it works in those three regex testers

Answer (score 0):

/"([^"])+?"/

Think this should work, untested though. Add a g to the end if you want it to match more than one for instances like a replace.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats like the same thing I have, at least it does the same thing.

Comment: Keep in mind if you do a replace on my example on say "content" replace with "abc" it will result in ""abc"" because the quotes are not within the parenthesis.

Comment: Tested mine at http://regexpal.com/ and it works.  Could you post the context in which you are using the regex? Aka the line of code that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for nesting parenthesis you need to add `:`, you can do something like this:

`[^:]\(\"([^"]+)?\"\)`

But if your string can start with: `("content")`, you should, additionally, do another test:

`^\(\"([^"]+)?\"\)`